# Do class skill bonuses stack when multiclassing?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, multi-classing

So, let's say I'm multiclassing Barbarian and Fighter and I take climb as a skill. Would I get a +3 from both classes, or only from one?

Comment: Welcome to rpg.se! Please take a look at the [tour](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/about) and the [help](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/help); they're a useful introduction to the site. And once you have 20+ rep, feel free to [join the chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11/rpg-general-chat)!

Comment: Please include which system you’re using as a tag in questions. This one seems almost-certainly to be *Pathfinder*, but there are thousands of systems out there.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

No, the Class Skill bonuses are a one-time-only (per skill) thing.<sup>1</sup> See the [PFSRD](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills#TOC-Class-Skills):

> ### Class Skills
>
> In addition, each class has a number of favored skills, called **class skills**. It is easier for your character to become more proficient in these skills, as they represent part of his professional training and constant practice. You gain a +3 bonus on all class skills that you put ranks into. *If you have more than one class and both grant you a class skill bonus, these bonuses do not stack.*

(*emphasis* mine)

Multiclassing does give you the +3 bonus to any skills you already had, but had not previously been a class skill, however.

> If you select a level in a new class, all of its class skills are automatically added to your list of class skills, and you gain a +3 bonus on these skills if you have ranks in them.

Really minor footnote, probably not worth reading:

<sup>1</sup> *Super-strictly* speaking, you *do* have the bonus twice, but since they are equal and do not stack, that will never become relevant (i.e. you have a +3 bonus and a +3 bonus, and have to pick just one – it doesn’t end up mattering which you pick).

Comment: I think you have to difference two things. First: You get +3 on class skills. Second: On multiclassing any skills may become class skills. If a skill is already a class skill it won´t develop any further. But I guess it´s just another wording.

Comment: @DocSnuggles Yes, that’s what I’m saying, or rather what the rules are saying.